# how to trim consecutive whitespace from beginning/end of file via sed

Tags: sed, whitespace, removing-whitespace

Using `sed`, how can I trim one or more *consecutive* whitespace-only lines from the beginning and/or end of a file?  (By "whitespace-only", I mean lines which do not contain any non-whitespace characters, i.e. lines which are either blank or only include whitespace characters.)

For example if my file is:

```
<blank line>
<line only containing some space/tab characters>
<blank line>
foo
bar
<tab character>
baz
<space character>
<space character><tab character>
qux
<tab character>
```

then the desired output would be:

```
foo
bar
<tab character>
baz
<space character>
<space character><tab character>
qux
```

If trimming from the beginning and end of the file have to be done in separate `sed` invocations, that's OK, although I'd also be interested in solutions which manage it all within one invocation.

P.S. This is easy in Perl / Ruby etc., but I'd specifically like to know if it's possible in `sed`.  Thanks!

Comment: You want to delete, entirely, any runs of whitespace-only lines but leave single whitespace-only lines alone?

Comment: No, single whitespace-only lines at the beginning / end of the file should also be trimmed.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer the question. Should single ws-only lines in the middle of the file be deleted? Should consecutive ws-only lines in the middle of the file be collapsed to one line or deleted? All ws-only lines at the start and end should be deleted that much seems clear.

Comment: @EdMorton because it's a fun challenge and a good exercise in honing `sed` skills!

Comment: @EtanReisner The question specifically limited the trimming to the beginning and end of the file, therefore the middle of the file shouldn't be touched at all.  The updated question should make this even clearer.

Comment: @EdMorton I guess you've never experienced the joy of taking part in an obfuscated code competition :-)  There are genuine reasons for deliberately writing unmaintainable code ...

Comment: Shall I send you the link for `lisp` implemented in `sed`?

Comment: Haha yes please @shellter!!

Comment: Here you go :-) https://github.com/shinh/sedlisp ! Enjoy, enjoy! ;-)

Comment: Also see http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/29b8c5/lisp_implementation_in_sed/ . Good luck to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any real sed experts popping up with a solution yet so here's my attempt (GNU sed specific due to `\S` and `\s` - replace with `[^[:space:]]` and `[[:space:]]` respectively for POSIX):

```
$ sed -e '/\S/,$!d' -e :a -e '/^\s*$/{$d;N;ba' -e '}' file
foo
bar

baz


qux
```

And in case anyone wants to see a sensible approach to compare to whatever arcane sed incantation IS eventually invoked, here's one way using GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `\s` abbreviation for `[[:space:]]`:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' '{gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"")}1' file
foo
bar

baz


qux
```

POSIX equivalent if you're happy picking some control char you know can't be in your input (e.g. using `^C` = a literal `control-C` char):

```
awk -v RS='^C' '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")}1' file
```

otherwise:

```
awk '{rec=rec $0 RS} END{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",rec); print rec}' file
```

or if you are limited in memory and cant read the whole file at once you need 2 passes to identify where the last non-blank line is, e.g.:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if(NF){if(!beg)beg=NR; end=NR}; next} (FNR>=beg)&&(FNR<=end)' file file
```

or you need to buffer the blank lines (after the initial set of them) until you hit a non-blank line and then print that buffer before the current line:

```
awk 'NF{printf "%s%s\n",buf,$0; buf=""; f=1; next} f{buf = buf $0 RS}' file
```

Comment: Nice, but how would you do this with a vanilla POSIX awk?

Comment: I added a couple of POSIX equivalents.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  It should also be possible without having to slurp more than one paragraph into memory at a time, but I didn't bother to implement that yet.

Comment: It is, but you need 2 passes or a buffer of blank lines that gets printed when you hit a non-blank line. I added versions that do both of those.

Comment: @AdamSpiers Hmm, I thought we'd be buried in heaps of letters and punctuation characters intermingled with runes and the batman symbol by now. Wonder where all the sed-ies are.... I updated my answer to include a sed solution for now, I expect someone else will come along with a better one.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly the kind of `sed` solution I suspected would exist!  For GNU sed, it can be shortened to `sed '/\S/,$!d; :a /^\s*$/{$d;N;ba}'. I think I was aware that a POSIX version would require at least one `-e`, but why does it need *three* of them?

Comment: It might not, you might want to leave this open until some sed expert comes along and abbreviates it into a quantum singularity. I've only been using sed for 32 years so I don't have my black belt yet :-). Seriously though, it's just not worth learning this stuff - it's like studying to become a typewriter repairman.