# How do I solve the issue of "Error (genfile::MalformedInputError)" when attempting to use QCTools_V2

Tags: shell, genetics

New user to stackoverflow.

I am trying to read in a `.gen.gz` file into `qctools` and retrieve specific `SNPs` from *a .txt* file which I've already specified.

Originally the `.gen.gz` file was in `.bgen` format but I deleted the `.bgen` suffix replacing it with `.gen.gz` (not sure if this is correct?). I am receiving an error:

`"Error (genfile::MalformedInputError" source is malformed on line 1"`

I read elsewhere that this could be an issue with trailing **whitespace** in the file, and I was wondering if anyone could provide guidance as to how to remove this trailing **whitespace**.

I have tried using:

```
sed -i 's/ /' filename
```

But my terminal gives me this error:

```
"sed: 1: "ukbxxxx_c1_b0_v3.bgen": invalid command code u"
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated
-Noah

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to trim consecutive whitespace from beginning/end of file via sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707574/how-to-trim-consecutive-whitespace-from-beginning-end-of-file-via-sed)

Comment: Thank you VictorLee, much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you converting it to`.gen.gz` file? You can use `qctool` to read `.bgen` files I guess.